# Using different implementations for one interface in Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, quartz

I want to do the following.

I implemented a scheduler with Quartz.Net and for IOC I use Autofac. 
Now I want to start one job multiple times but the data base is different for each job. My repository takes a parameter, that wraps my connection string.
The parameter is of type `IOptions<T>` and is injected in the constructor of the repository. The repository is also injected in different services.

The Problem is, that I can't acces the repository directly, because there are many services involved, which all use the same repository.

The repository is implemented by someone else and it contains multiple queries and one connection string property. I have different data bases for different countries (sales system) but they are all the same, so I just have one repository for all the data bases.

The connection strings are read from a JSON file:

```
{
  "PriceListSettings": [
    {
      "Country": "DE",
      "ConnectionString": "Initial Catalog=Catalog_DE;Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true;",
      "ExecutionTime": "0 0 0 1/1 * ? *"
    },
    {
      "Country": "AT",
      "ConnectionString": "Initial Catalog=Catalog_AT;Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true;",
      "ExecutionTime": "0 0 0 1/1 * ? *"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to have a scope for each job, so that I can inject or set a different connection string.

With Quarz you can set a trigger. The problem is, that the jobs are all starting at configurable times and shall be executed once per night. But I don't know exactly when.

I tried to use

```
using (var scope = Program.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    //Does not seem to work this way
    //var repo = scope.Resolve<IRepository>();
    //repo.PricelistServiceConfig = priceListConfig;            
}
```

I also tried to let Quartz run in single thread but it seems, that I can't set the property of my repo correctly.

Frameworks used:

- .Net Framework 4.6 (can't upgrade)
- Autofac 4.8.1
- Autofac.Extras.Quartz 4.2.0
- Quartz 3.0.6

Comment: So you want to have multiple repositories with different connection objects and then get all those? This sounds like an Adapter pattern (Repository adapts the connection string) You should then be able to resolve all adapted connection objects

Comment: The repository is implemented by someone else and it contains multiple queries and one connection string property. I have diferent data bases for different countries (sales system) but they are all the same, so I just have one repository for all the data bases. I will update my question

Comment: But you still have one repository instance per "job" (each having a different connection string), correct? If so, how are those connection strings represented? Do you have an array or a list of those? Dictionary? Custom class? (how do you get the "correct" string for the job?)

Comment: yeah that's correct. I read the connectionstrings from a json file. I initialize the Jobs based on the number of listings in my json. So i know which job needs to connect to which db. I just can't manage to set them

Comment: Then _possible_ tools are [resolve parameters](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html) and/or [property injection](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html) , if you provide some standalone code with example classes and/or interfaces maybe I can formulate an answer for this generalized problem. (boiled down to basic classes without quartz)

Comment: Another solution: Create a `Job` class that takes a blank repository instance and the configuration parameters and then bootstraps the repository

Comment: Your links got me working, thanks. I remembered that there is a JobDataMap and with it I can set the connection string in my repo. I don't inject it anymore, so I have to create some fallback. By time I have a closer look at resolving parameters at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that you almost got it. I don't know how exactly your classes look like, so I made up an example with some stub implementaion for `Job`, `Reposiroty` and services classes. There is a job that receives two services into contructor. Both of the services requires repository as parameter to their constructors:

```
[Test]
public void AutofacLifetimeScope()
{
    // Arrange
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<Job>();
    builder.RegisterType<AnotherService>();
    builder.RegisterType<SomeService>();
    builder.RegisterType<Repository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().WithProperty(ResolvedParameter.ForKeyed<Option>("opt"));

    var container = builder.Build();

    // Act
    Job job1;
    var option1 = new Option {ConnectinString = "DE Connection"};
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(c => c.RegisterInstance(option1).Keyed<Option>("opt")))
    {
        job1 = scope.Resolve<Job>();
    }

    Job job2;
    var option2 = new Option { ConnectinString = "AT Connection" };
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(c => c.RegisterInstance(option2).Keyed<Option>("opt")))
    {
        job2 = scope.Resolve<Job>();
    }

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(job1.SomeService.Repository.PriceListConfig, option1);
    Assert.AreEqual(job1.AnotherService.Repository.PriceListConfig, option1);

    Assert.AreEqual(job2.SomeService.Repository.PriceListConfig, option2);
    Assert.AreEqual(job2.AnotherService.Repository.PriceListConfig, option2);
}

public class Repository
{
    public Option PriceListConfig { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    public string ConnectinString { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string ExecutionTime { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public SomeService SomeService { get; }
    public AnotherService AnotherService { get; }

    public Job(SomeService someService, AnotherService anotherService)
    {
        SomeService = someService;
        AnotherService = anotherService;
    }
}

public class AnotherService
{
    public Repository Repository { get; }

    public AnotherService(Repository repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }
}

public class SomeService
{
    public Repository Repository { get; }

    public SomeService(Repository repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }
}
```

The main idea is to register `Repository` per lifetime scope with property injection, that will be cofigured later during the creating of lifetime scope. I made injected instances available through public properties. Just for simple testing of the example. Hope it helps.